# How to assign specific role to a user for a group in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, user-roles

I created a group in keycloak and i added users to the group. I want to add one user as the group admin of the group by adding ADMIN role to one user and other users should remain with USER role.

One user can belongs to multiple groups. As an example `User_A` can be in `Group_A`, `Group_B` and `Group_C`. And also `User_A` is the admin of `Group_A` and in `Group_B` and `Group_C`, he is a normal user.

Is there any way to achieve this requirement in keycloak?

Please let me know is there any solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a sub-group `admin` with default ADMIN role below `Group_A` , and put User A in that sub-group.

Or why don't you just assign individual ADMIN role to `User_A` ?
As I understand `groups` function in keycloak, it is essentially a way of assigning automatic attributes/roles to user (and...to group them). But roles assigned via `groups` function are exactly the same as individual roles I think.